# Is it possible to call a MPGW from IBM APIConnect?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-datapower, apiconnect

I have my API manager hosted on kubernetes runtime and also datapower running virtually and can be accessed through docker. For one of  use case I am required to create a MPGW and call the same from the APIConnect.When I tried to use the gateway url that is configured in cloud manager I am getting 404 error . So I want more insights on how is this achievable?
Pls help with your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Set up a MPGW with a http listener for 127.0.0.1 and a port in the high range, e.g. 58080 or something.
Then call the MPGW using http://127.0.0.1:58080/your-uri

The listener won't be available from the cluster, only internal calls and make sure to add the same to all DataPower instances in the cluster.

Comment: When I tried running my mpgw like above I am getting "Httphostconnectexception:connection refused".

Comment: If you add the lister (FSH) to 127.0.0.1 you can only call it from another DataPower service on the same instance. If you want to test it from another Client you need to use 0.0.0.0 as the listener (or the IP/Alias of the exposed NIC)